# Suddenly error coming up in content repository when accessing documents stored

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan, jcr, modeshape

Widlfly machine is setup with modeshape which uses infinispan.

When i try to accesing documebnts stored through front end, suddenly below error is coming up.

execution error: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.persistenceexception: java.io.ioexception: unsupported protocol version 0

before this server ran out of memory problem. I took backup of logs and freed the space before restarting the server then this problem is popping up.

What might have gone wrong and is there any to recover files. I can see files in there so there was no evidence of data loss.

Below is the error

ISPN000136: Execution error: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 0
rshalledEntryImpl.java:114) [infinispan-core-6.0.2.Final.jar:6.0.2.Final]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Modeshape has not seen any development in the last 5 years and is effectively abandoned. It's unlikely you will be able to find someone who can help you